# Is it difficult to do a car border crossing in Kaliningrad Oblast?

Tags: russia, borders, automobiles, kaliningrad

Assuming I have the correct visa and intend to drive in from the Polish side, should I anticipate any problems crossing the border quickly?

I ask because [Wikitravel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Kaliningrad_Oblast) says:

> You will need Russian visa. Even if you have one it may take days to get in by car.

Which makes me wonder why it might take days.

Answer (score 11):

You know, Kaliningrad is a trade city, and there are many people who use cars to move with goods to resell, so sometimes there are a lot of cars going through the border station.

From other side, the old border station in [Mamononvo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mamonovo) is not very big, which causes additional problems during crossing the border.

Also, Kaliningrad has many strategic places nearby, so sometimes the security aspect can cause the problem (even if it is not your car, you still have to wait).

But I think that Wikitravel containss kind of old information - nearly a year ago a new border station was opened in [Mamonovo-2/Grzechotki](http://maps.google.ru/maps?q=Grzechotki,%20Polska&hl=ru&ie=UTF8&geocode=%20&hnear=Grzechotki,%20%D0%91%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8F%D1%82,%20%D0%92%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE,%20%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B0&t=m&z=14&vpsrc=0), after that the federal autobahn [Berlinka](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlinka) was continued, and the traffic situation became easier.

Still, during holidays you can meet traffic at the border stations. You can check the situation at the border [online](http://www.ektotrans.ru/borderline.php). The left column is to Kaliningrad, the right one is to Poland.

Also, I want add information about the visa - even if you don't have one, you can get a [Kaliningrad 72 hours visa](http://www.konigsberg.ru/eng/kaliningrad/express-visa.htm) (maximum staying period is 4 days 3 nights), if you are citizen of Shengen countries, UK or Japan.

Comment: I think it is worth mentioning that the numbers on the referenced online traffic tracking page is the number of cars waiting in line. Also, the generalization of that answer is - no, you will not have to spend a few days to get in to Kaliningrad county. Worst case is several hours.