# Is it possible to get a visa for Kaliningrad in the neighboring countries?

Tags: visas, russia, poland, kaliningrad, baltic-region

I am planning to visit Northern Poland and then Lithuania, Latvia and Estonia. I am thinking of going into the Russian state of Kaliningrad as well. I've read that compared to Russia proper it is easier to get a three day tourist visa for Kaliningrad. You don't need an invitation like for main land Russia.

I have a German passport and will leave from Berlin in the next few days. Is it possible to get a Kaliningrad visa in Gdansk or Vilnius in a day?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[From quick search, I found out](http://www.konigsberg.ru/eng/kaliningrad/express-visa.htm), that (as EU citizen) you can get 72-hours visa to Kaliningrad at the border.

> You can get 72 hours visa only at 3 points:
>   - Kaliningrad airport, if you arrive by plane
>   - Russian-Polish border (Bagrationovsk and Mamonovo).

Another way is to get your visa in Poland is in consulate in Warsaw, but that may take longer.

Comment: I should add that this methods **can** be unavailable from January, 1st 2015 as a part of reaction for sanctions [off.site](http://kaliningrad.mid.ru/-/prekrasaetsa-vydaca-kratkosrocnyh-turisticeskih-viz)

Answer (score 4):

If you are departing from Berlin, you can use the Mamonovo post to get this visa right there, with no need to wait, as @Tschareck said. There is new road opened, more information is in our older question here: ["Is it difficult to do a car border crossing in Kaliningrad Oblast?"](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4410/is-it-difficult-to-do-a-car-border-crossing-in-kaliningrad-oblast)