# Is it possible to enter Kaliningrad via Poland and leave via Lithuania?

Tags: visas, russia, poland, kaliningrad, lithuania

When entering the Kaliningrad Oblast via some specific entry points, [EU citizens can get a visa for 72 hours at the border](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/8764/3470). This information can also be found on an [official site](http://www.kaliningrad.mid.ru/eng/acc_002.html).

Now I would like to know if with such a visa one has also to leave via these border points.

Indeed, is this procedure also valid if a EU citizen enters Kaliningrad via Poland, and leaves it in less than 72 hours via Lithuania? Or will she have to apply for a "traditional" visa in that case, as the border crossings with Lithuania are not part of this special visa program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the same site nothing is indicated whether the entry and exit points must be the same.  The only thing that is prescribed on the [official site](http://www.kaliningrad.mid.ru/eng/acc_002.html) are the points of entry, which given the fact that [Khrabrovo Airport](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khrabrovo_Airport) is on the list of possible entry points means that the origination country doesn't have to be Poland.

There is a tourist site [konigsberg.ru](http://www.konigsberg.ru/eng/kaliningrad/express-visa.htm/comment-page-2#comment-960) where this exact question was asked before, so your exit to Lithuania is not an issue.